# Casting a void* pointer

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, casting, void-pointers

i have a problem in my code when i try to use compelx structure in a generic sorting library on C lang: (you can find the complete code https://github.com/Tramontz/ASD_2023)

i have a binary-merge insertion sort, thatt take in imput a void pointer (first element of an array), and ,can work with array of int and string (all unity test pass).

Now i'm tryng to use it with an array of:

```
struct record{
  int id;
  char* string_field_1;
  int integer_field_2;
  double float_field_3;
};
```

stored in another struct

```
struct _StructArray{
  void**array;
  unsigned long el_num;
  unsigned long array_capacity;
};
```

with subroutine

```
void struct_array_add(StructArray *struct_array, void* element){
  if(struct_array->el_num >= struct_array->array_capacity){
    printf("array too short, must be reallocate \n");
    struct_array->array = (void**)realloc(struct_array->array,2*(struct_array->array_capacity)*sizeof(void*));
    struct_array->array_capacity = 2*struct_array->array_capacity;
  }
  struct_array->array[struct_array->el_num] = element;
  struct_array->el_num++;
}

void* struct_array_get(StructArray *struct_array, unsigned long index){
  return &(struct_array->array)[index];
}
```

i must order the void**array of record.

this is an example of the data took from a csv file

<POSIZION:0, ID:0, String:noto, Integer:233460, Float:32209.073312 >

<POSIZION:1, ID:1, String:piangea, Integer:4741192, Float:81176.622633 >

<POSIZION:2, ID:2, String:spenti!, Integer:1014671, Float:4476.013614 >

<POSIZION:3, ID:3, String:misericordia, Integer:496325, Float:61628.929334 >

the ordering mode is choosed by

```
switch (field) {
      case 1://struct_array_get(array,0) return the first element of the array
          merge_binary_insertion_sort(struct_array_get(array,0), struct_array_size(array), sizeof(struct record), k, precedes_record_string_field);
```

so basically i store with a loop all my data in the record *array inside structArray.

the array is correctly loaded, because the print function

```
for(unsigned long i=0;i<el_num;i++){
    array_element = (struct record *)struct_array_get(array, i);
    printf("<POSIZION:%d, ID:%d, String:%s, Integer:%d, Float:%lf >\n",i,array_element->id,array_element->string_field_1,array_element->integer_field_2,array_element->float_field_3); 
  }
```

can show all the record in the array.

so the problem appear when the sorting function is called:

```
    void bin_insertion_sort(void *arr, int n, size_t elementSize, CompareFunction compare) {
        int i, loc, j;
        void *selected = malloc(elementSize);
        if (selected == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione di memoria per 'selected'\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
        for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            j = i - 1;
            memcpy(selected, arr + i * elementSize, elementSize);

            // Find location where selected should be inserted
            loc = binary_search(arr, selected, 0, j, compare, elementSize);
```

i store in the void *selected the item that i want to find location in the array, and call the binary search

```
int binary_search(void *arr, void *item, int low, int high, CompareFunction compare, size_t elementSize) {
        if (high <= low){
            return (compare(item, arr + low * elementSize) > 0) ? (low + 1) : low ;
```

We can focus only in the binary_search, here is the problem:
when i call **return (compare(item, arr + low * elementSize) > 0) ? (low + 1) : low ;**
for the records's array, with this compare function

```
 static int precedes_record_string_field(const void* r1_p, const void* r2_p) {
    if (r1_p == NULL || r2_p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "precedes_record_string_field: one of the parameters is a null pointer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const struct record* rec1_p = (const struct record*)r1_p;
    const struct record* rec2_p = (const struct record*)r2_p;

    printf("Record 1: ID=%d, String=%s, Integer=%d, Float=%f\n", rec1_p->id, rec1_p->string_field_1, rec1_p->integer_field_2, rec1_p->float_field_3);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Record 2: ID=%d, String=%s, Integer=%d, Float=%f\n", rec2_p->id, rec2_p->string_field_1, rec2_p->integer_field_2, rec2_p->float_field_3);
sleep(5);

    return strcmp(rec1_p->string_field_1, rec2_p->string_field_1);
}
```

it print the rec2 data, but not the rec1 data, so i suppose that it can cast the **arr + low * elementSize** pointer, but not the **void* item** pointer that I pass through the compare(item, arr + low * elementSize) and store in rec1(item) and rec2(arr + low * elementSize).

I'm doing something wrong in the memory adress management?
maybe i'm adressing all the structArray with item, and not the second element of the record* array?

i'm stucked because all my unity test with single, null, and multiple string and integer arrays work correctly.

Thank you all.

Comment: Is that really the [mre] you're posting?

Comment: Also, have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? See where it might go wrong?

Comment: The issue is certainly not the cast, provided that there is indeed an object of the struct type. The error can be anything -- memory management, pointer arithmetic, a typo.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on void pointers so `arr + low * elementSize` is gibberish.

Comment: @Lundin The standard forbids it but [gcc allows it as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html), and it is done [in the Linux kernel](https://lkml.org/lkml/2022/2/24/978).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I know that, but nothing in the question indicates that the OP is doing kernel goo programming. In normal C programming, we stay away from bad practices. In Linux kernel programming, we embrace bad practices and actively seek to use them... The overall ambition of SO should be to teach good programming practices.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium it's complicate to simplify that kind of code, i'm sorry if it seems verbose

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica debugged with gdb, console show a " Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."
but i can't figure out why unity test work properly

Comment: @Favio Simplification is likely the road to finding the bug.

Comment: ok, i simplified the code, focusing on where i pass the void pointer from the source to the comparator's casting.

Comment: `if (high <= low){` looks very suspicious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very very very complex the way you wrote.

```
Maybe you could test the functions first...

I will show you a methodical way of writing his,
using your `struct` and `qsort`,
that you can easily adapt...
```

> > **EDIT: added a second part, PART II, below. In that I added code to use the same method below to sort a `void**` array, and then a `StructArray` as in the original question, as an example of a way to separate the container, the methods and the algorithm. This was a heavy use of copy and paste: the changes are only in the compare functions (2 lines in each) and a function added to `StructArray` (4 lines) to extract he base address of the array of pointers.**

#### keep things separated

```
typedef struct
{
    int    id;
    char*  string;
    int    i_field;
    double d_field;
} Target;

int cmp_1(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_2(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_3(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_4(const void*, const void*);

int so_show(unsigned, Target[], const char*);
```

Here we have your data record, the 4 required functions and a function to show the results

Use **encapsulation** and write code around your data.

See this :

```
    Target some_value[] = {
        [0] =
            {.id      = 42,
             .string  = "value 33",
             .i_field = 4242,
             .d_field = 42.42},
        [1] =
            {.id      = 4,
             .string  = "stack",
             .i_field = 42,
             .d_field = 42.242},
        [2] =
            {.id      = 342,
             .string  = "overflow",
             .i_field = 4,
             .d_field = 142.42},
        [3] =
            {.id      = 412,
             .string  = "take the survey",
             .i_field = 2,
             .d_field = 2142.42},
};
```

This is data to test all your functions.

###' `main` for a test ###

Here:

- the array is printed as declared
- the array is sorted by each criteria and displayed

```
    so_show(4, some_value, "\nBefore sort:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_1);
    so_show(4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by id:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_2);
    so_show(
        4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by string field:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_3);
    so_show(
        4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by integer field:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_4);
    so_show(
        4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by double field:\t");
```

#### the output

```
Before sort:    4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|=========================================================|


After sort by id:       4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|=========================================================|


After sort by string field:     4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|=========================================================|


After sort by integer field:    4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|=========================================================|


After sort by double field:     4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|=========================================================|
```

And it seems to be ok.

It is easier this way: first test all functions.

Since you said the code already works for integers, just make sure the sorting code really abstracted the data record.
In general is just a case of writing correct swapping functions. And paying special attention to the navigating process...

#### complete `C` code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int    id;
    char*  string;
    int    i_field;
    double d_field;
}  Target;

int cmp_1(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_2(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_3(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_4(const void*, const void*);

int so_show(unsigned, Target[], const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Target some_value[] = {
        [0] =
            {.id      = 42,
             .string  = "value 33",
             .i_field = 4242,
             .d_field = 42.42},
        [1] =
            {.id      = 4,
             .string  = "stack",
             .i_field = 42,
             .d_field = 42.242},
        [2] =
            {.id      = 342,
             .string  = "overflow",
             .i_field = 4,
             .d_field = 142.42},
        [3] =
            {.id      = 412,
             .string  = "take the survey",
             .i_field = 2,
             .d_field = 2142.42},
    };

    so_show(4, some_value, "\nBefore sort:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_1);
    so_show(4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by id:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_2);
    so_show(
        4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by string field:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_3);
    so_show(
        4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by integer field:\t");

    qsort(some_value, 4, sizeof(Target), cmp_4);
    so_show(
        4, some_value, "\nAfter sort by double field:\t");

};  // main

int cmp_1(void* one, void* other)
{
    Target* a = one;
    Target* b = other;
    if (a->id < b->id) return -1;
    if (a->id == b->id) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_2(void* one, void* other)
{   // now for the string
    Target* a = one;
    Target* b = other;
    return strcmp(a->string, b->string);
};

int cmp_3(void* one, void* other)
{
    Target* a = one;
    Target* b = other;
    if (a->i_field < b->i_field) return -1;
    if (a->i_field == b->i_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_4(void* one, void* other)
{
    Target* a = one;
    Target* b = other;
    if (a->d_field < b->d_field) return -1;
    if (a->d_field == b->d_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};
int so_show(unsigned N, Target r[], const char* msg)
{
    if (r == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d records\n", N);
    const char* l0 =
        "\
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |";
    const char* l1 =
        "\
|=========================================================|";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", l1,l0,l1);
    for ( unsigned u=0;u<N;u+=1)
        printf(
            "| %4d | \"%20s\" | %8d | %12.4f |\n", r[u].id,
            r[u].string, r[u].i_field, r[u].d_field);
    printf("%s\n\n",l1);
    return 0;
}
```

### Part II

This is `main.c` for the second example:

```
int main(void)
{
    Target some_value[] = {
        [0] =
            {.id      = 42,
             .string  = "value 33",
             .i_field = 4242,
             .d_field = 42.42},
        [1] =
            {.id      = 4,
             .string  = "stack",
             .i_field = 42,
             .d_field = 42.242},
        [2] =
            {.id      = 342,
             .string  = "overflow",
             .i_field = 4,
             .d_field = 142.42},
        [3] =
            {.id      = 412,
             .string  = "take the survey",
             .i_field = 2,
             .d_field = 2142.42},
    };

    const N = sizeof(some_value) / sizeof(some_value[0]);

    test_with_struct_array(
        N, some_value,
        "\n\n\t***** using an array of structs *****\n\n");
    test_with_voidp_array(
        N, some_value,
        "\n\n\t***** using a 'void**' *****\n\n");
    test_with_Struct_Array(
        N, some_value,
        "\n\n\t***** using an original 'StructArray' "
        "*****\n\n");

    return 0;
};  // main
```

`test_with_struct_array()` is the original program. The 2nd function sorts the same array in a `void**` array, in order to test the mechanics in isolation, and the 3rd function uses the author's original `StructArray` --- with a minor modification, see code below.

#### usind a `void**`

This is the code to build the array using the original data:

```
    Target** base = malloc(n * sizeof(Target*));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        base[i] = &some_value[i];
```

The compare funcions are all different, since there is a new level of indirection to accesss the actual data. The new functions are `cmp_[5678]` from `cmp_[1234]` and here is a pair, that compares the `i_field` from `Target`:

```
int cmp_3(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    Target* a = (Target*)one;
    Target* b = (Target*)other;
    if (a->i_field < b->i_field) return -1;
    if (a->i_field == b->i_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_7(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    Target* a = (Target*)*((const void**)one);
    Target* b = (Target*)*((const void**)other);
    if (a->i_field < b->i_field) return -1;
    if (a->i_field == b->i_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};
```

The difference is just in getting the data address. Since `StructArray` is also a `void**` thing, these functions are used there too.

Sister functions were added to display the data from the different sources, so the output is exactly the same, as expected.

```
int so_show_one(Target*);
int so_show(
    unsigned, Target[], int (*show)(void*), const char*);
int so_show_from_StructArray(
    StructArray*, int (*show)(void*), const char*);
int so_show_from_voidp_array(
    unsigned, void**, int (*show)(void*), const char*);
```

The first function displays a single data record, so can be used by all 3 formats. It is passed as a parameter so it is easy to use an alternate display for each test if needed.

#### The change in `StructArray`

```
void* struct_array_get_base(StructArray* x)
{
    if (x == NULL) return NULL;
    return &(x->array)[0];
}
```

This function was added in order to get the base address from inside `StructArray`

#### On using `StructArray` as a container

```
int test_with_Struct_Array(
    unsigned n, Target some_value[], const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);

    StructArray* tgt = struct_array_create();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        struct_array_add(tgt, &some_value[i]);
    fprintf(
        stderr, "\n\t%u values inside target StructArray\n",
        struct_array_size(tgt));

    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one,
        "\n    With data inside StructArray:\t");

    // this is the base for sort
    void*  array_base = struct_array_get_base(tgt);
    size_t size       = struct_array_size(tgt);
    qsort(array_base, size, sizeof(void*), cmp_5);
    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one, "\n\tAfter sort by id:\t");
```

This is how the container was abstracted for sorting, at the start of the test function. This should work for any sorting algorithm on the contiguous array of `void*`.

Hope it helps

#### code for the second example

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
#pragma pack(show)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "struct_array.h"

typedef struct
{
    int    id;
    char*  string;
    int    i_field;
    double d_field;
} Target;

int cmp_1(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_2(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_3(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_4(const void*, const void*);

int cmp_5(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_6(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_7(const void*, const void*);
int cmp_8(const void*, const void*);

int so_show_one(Target*);
int so_show(
    unsigned, Target[], int (*show)(void*), const char*);
int so_show_from_StructArray(
    StructArray*, int (*show)(void*), const char*);
int so_show_from_voidp_array(
    unsigned, void**, int (*show)(void*), const char*);

int test_with_struct_array(unsigned, Target[], const char*);
int test_with_voidp_array(unsigned, Target[], const char*);
int test_with_Struct_Array(unsigned, Target[], const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Target some_value[] = {
        [0] =
            {.id      = 42,
             .string  = "value 33",
             .i_field = 4242,
             .d_field = 42.42},
        [1] =
            {.id      = 4,
             .string  = "stack",
             .i_field = 42,
             .d_field = 42.242},
        [2] =
            {.id      = 342,
             .string  = "overflow",
             .i_field = 4,
             .d_field = 142.42},
        [3] =
            {.id      = 412,
             .string  = "take the survey",
             .i_field = 2,
             .d_field = 2142.42},
    };

    const N = sizeof(some_value) / sizeof(some_value[0]);

    test_with_struct_array(
        N, some_value,
        "\n\n\t***** using an array of structs *****\n\n");
    test_with_voidp_array(
        N, some_value,
        "\n\n\t***** using a 'void**' *****\n\n");
    test_with_Struct_Array(
        N, some_value,
        "\n\n\t***** using an original 'StructArray' "
        "*****\n\n");

    return 0;
};  // main

int cmp_1(const void* one, const void* other)
{  // compare ids
    Target* a = (Target*)one;
    Target* b = (Target*)other;
    if (a->id < b->id) return -1;
    if (a->id == b->id) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_2(const void* one, const void* other)
{  // now for the string
    Target* a = (Target*)one;
    Target* b = (Target*)other;
    return strcmp(a->string, b->string);
};

int cmp_3(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    Target* a = (Target*)one;
    Target* b = (Target*)other;
    if (a->i_field < b->i_field) return -1;
    if (a->i_field == b->i_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_4(const void* one, const void* other)
{  // for doubles
    Target* a = (Target*)one;
    Target* b = (Target*)other;
    if (a->d_field < b->d_field) return -1;
    if (a->d_field == b->d_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_5(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    Target* a = (Target*)*((const void**)one);
    Target* b = (Target*)*((const void**)other);
    if (a->id < b->id) return -1;
    if (a->id == b->id) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_6(const void* one, const void* other)
{  // now for the string
    Target* a = (Target*)*((const void**)one);
    Target* b = (Target*)*((const void**)other);
    return strcmp(a->string, b->string);
};

int cmp_7(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    Target* a = (Target*)*((const void**)one);
    Target* b = (Target*)*((const void**)other);
    if (a->i_field < b->i_field) return -1;
    if (a->i_field == b->i_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int cmp_8(const void* one, const void* other)
{  // sort as double
    Target* a = *((void**)one);
    Target* b = *((void**)other);
    if (a->d_field < b->d_field) return -1;
    if (a->d_field == b->d_field) return 0;
    return 1;
};

int so_show(
    unsigned N, Target r[], int (*show)(void*),
    const char* msg)
{
    if (r == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d records\n", N);
    const char* l0 =
        "\
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |";
    const char* l1 =
        "\
|=========================================================|";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", l1, l0, l1);
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < N; u += 1) show(r + u);
    printf("%s\n\n", l1);
    return 0;
}

int so_show_one(Target* one)
{
    printf(
        "| %4d | \"%20s\" | %8d | %12.4f |\n", one->id,
        one->string, one->i_field, one->d_field);
    return 0;
}

int so_show_from_StructArray(
    StructArray* A, int (*show)(void*), const char* msg)
{
    if (A == NULL) return -1;
    if (show == NULL) return -2;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    unsigned long N = struct_array_size(A);
    printf("%u records\n", N);
    const char* l0 =
        "\
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |";
    const char* l1 =
        "\
|=========================================================|";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", l1, l0, l1);
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < N; u += 1)
        show((Target*)struct_array_get(A, u));
    printf("%s\n\n", l1);
    return 0;
}

int so_show_from_voidp_array(
    unsigned N, void** base, int (*show)(void*),
    const char* msg)
{
    if (base == NULL) return -1;
    if (show == NULL) return -2;
    if (N <= 0) return -3;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%u records\n", N);
    const char* l0 =
        "\
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |";
    const char* l1 =
        "\
|=========================================================|";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", l1, l0, l1);
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < N; u += 1)
        show((Target*)base[u]);
    printf("%s\n\n", l1);
    return 0;
}

int test_with_struct_array(
    unsigned n, Target some_value[], const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);

    so_show(
        n, some_value, so_show_one, "\n    Before sort:\t");

    qsort(some_value, n, sizeof(Target), cmp_1);
    so_show(
        n, some_value, so_show_one,
        "\n    After sort by id:\t");

    qsort(some_value, n, sizeof(Target), cmp_2);
    so_show(
        n, some_value, so_show_one,
        "\n    After sort by string field:\t");

    qsort(some_value, n, sizeof(Target), cmp_3);
    so_show(
        n, some_value, so_show_one,
        "\n    After sort by integer field:\t");

    qsort(some_value, n, sizeof(Target), cmp_4);
    so_show(
        n, some_value, so_show_one,
        "\n    After sort by double field:\t");

    return 0;
}

int test_with_voidp_array(
    unsigned n, Target some_value[], const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);

    Target** base = malloc(n * sizeof(Target*));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        base[i] = &some_value[i];

    so_show_from_voidp_array(
        n, base, so_show_one, "\tbefore sort: ");

    size_t sz_one = sizeof(Target*);
    qsort(&base[0], n, sz_one, cmp_5);
    so_show_from_voidp_array(
        n, base, so_show_one, "\tsorted by id field: ");

    qsort(&base[0], n, sz_one, cmp_8);
    so_show_from_voidp_array(
        n, base, so_show_one, "\tsorted by double field: ");

    qsort(&base[0], n, sz_one, cmp_7);
    so_show_from_voidp_array(
        n, base, so_show_one,
        "\tsorted by integer field: ");

    qsort(&base[0], n, sz_one, cmp_6);
    so_show_from_voidp_array(
        n, base, so_show_one, "\tsorted by string field: ");
    return 0;
}

int test_with_Struct_Array(
    unsigned n, Target some_value[], const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);

    StructArray* tgt = struct_array_create();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        struct_array_add(tgt, &some_value[i]);
    fprintf(
        stderr, "\n\t%u values inside target StructArray\n",
        struct_array_size(tgt));

    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one,
        "\n    With data inside StructArray:\t");

    // this is the base for sort
    void*  array_base = struct_array_get_base(tgt);
    size_t size       = struct_array_size(tgt);
    qsort(array_base, size, sizeof(void*), cmp_5);
    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one, "\n\tAfter sort by id:\t");

    qsort(array_base, size, sizeof(void*), cmp_6);
    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one,
        "\n\tAfter sort by string field:\t");

    qsort(array_base, size, sizeof(void*), cmp_7);
    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one,
        "\n    After sort by integer field:\t");

    qsort(array_base, size, sizeof(void*), cmp_8);
    so_show_from_StructArray(
        tgt, so_show_one,
        "\n    After sort by double field:\t");

    return 0;
}
```

#### output for the 3rd test

Not interesting since it is the same data 3 times, but generated by differen containers built from the same original data.

```
        ***** using an original 'StructArray' *****


        4 values inside target StructArray

    With data inside StructArray:       4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|=========================================================|


        After sort by id:       4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|=========================================================|


        After sort by string field:     4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|=========================================================|


    After sort by integer field:        4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|=========================================================|


    After sort by double field: 4 records
|=========================================================|
|  id  |           string value |  integer |       double |
|=========================================================|
|    4 | "               stack" |       42 |      42.2420 |
|   42 | "            value 33" |     4242 |      42.4200 |
|  342 | "            overflow" |        4 |     142.4200 |
|  412 | "     take the survey" |        2 |    2142.4200 |
|=========================================================|
```

Comment: thank you, but after this try i think the problem is how my compare function cast from void* to the struct variable. the output, after i changed the sizeof is:
Record 1: ID=6893352, String=(null), Integer=-824954186, Float=0.000000
Record 2: ID=0, String=noto, Integer=233460, Float=32209.073312
so, the record 2 is correct, this mean that the cast from arr + low * elementSize work properly, but i can't understand where is pointing the record 1, that is the casting of a void* item pinter, builded this way: 
void *item= malloc(elementSize);
memcpy(selected, arr+ i* elementSize, elementSize);

Comment: Could you post the actual version of the code? Maybe on github or as an edit of the question? The way I wrote the 4 functions does no work for you? Do you have a tested swapping function?

Comment: i modified the information about my issue, and focused on the 2 call that don't work.
i tried your version, but it work because you call a library from C, i have to develop my own sorting library, so i think the problem is how i adress the void pointer

Comment: This question is not about sorting. What I showed was a (maybe) simpler way to code around the data and functions. The precise sorting function is not relevant. What is your definition of _binary-merge insertion sort_? Do you have a reference? Edit your answer and put it there so we can take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/Tramontz/ASD_2023

Comment: the difference between my code and yours is that you are using an array of struct that contain records, i use a struct StructArray that contain some information (like dimension of the array, capacity, method that make the array dinamic like realloc, get, set ecc), and a pointer to the first element of the array of record. maybe i make some error tring to reference the pointer to the correct element of the array starting from the first element of the array of the StructArray.

Comment: Good to have access the actual version of your code now. I know the difference between the 2, at least from the start. And that is why I told you the things I told you. It is too complex with no need (my opinion). What I do not know is what is your definition of _binary-merge insertion sort_ ?Is it the usual merge-insertion sort?

Comment: Keep in mind that you had been warned in the comments by @Lundin that there is no pointer arithmetic on `void*`. Use `char*` counting on their size being 1...

Comment: thank you for the reply: binary-merge insertion sort is an algo that, based on a parameter K, use binary insertion sort for order array with lenth < K, otherwise use merge sort.
I know that it's triky to do arithmetic with void pointer, but the request for the project is to use them, no char*, no BYTE ecc...
DO you think that the only solution is to avoid StructArray and use like you direcly an array of records? loosing feture like auto realloc if the array is too short ecc...

Comment: It is not _tricky_ It just do not exist. Just cast them when you need to operate on addresses. So you are implementing the standard merge-insertion sort a.k.a Ford-Johnson? About `StructArray`  and sort, the issue, as on any algorithm, is on traverse, compare and swap elements. Just confirm these operations are abstracted and are ok with your `struct`.

Comment: yes, it is, with binary search to help insertion sort selecting the swap.
i'm sure that these operation are abstracted, because work with any type of array. so i think that the traverse, compare and swap work properly except when i adress the **array element >[0] contained in StructArray

Comment: Well, later I will edit my example to sort on `Target` items inside `StructArray` and see how it goes. 
  - traverse the array is trivial since `StructArray` is just a pre-allocated array of `void*`.
  - swap is also trivial.
  - `compare` needs some attention ;)

Comment: Added a `Part II` and a new example using `StructArray` to feed a `qsort`, It should work for any algorithm, including your's

Comment: i tried with your indication, exept for the & in the struct_array_add, if i pass &element instead of element, the print array show only address and symbol in the field (i added the set and get routine in my question if you want to review them). anyway my code run untill i work inside main, when i pass argument to my sort function, it stop when i arrive in the compare, i think that the problem is in how i address the first and next element of the array. if you want and have some time you can find my cone on github, link is before. thank you a lot for you patience and time

Comment: Fabio. I still think the way you wrote this is too complex. Did you run the examples I wrote for you? They use the same `struct`.  Note that binary search should work also for any field you choose. Your array is just it: an array of `void*`. You can traverse the array using normal indexes. But you can also address each one using `struct_array_get`. But you can not mix these things. It is essential that you see this difference. This is why I added a function to get the base address. It makes things a lot easier. And faster.

Comment: following your example, i rewrited my code using as pointer for the array void** instead of void* and traverse it using Array[i] index, avoiding memory Arithmetics. thank you a lot!

Comment: And avoiding to use a function to access a record for sorting each time. This can have a huge impact on sorting times. Anyway there is no pointer arithmetic on `void*`.  This is why I wrote `struct_array_get_base()` in the example: `return &(x->array)[0];`